# Creating a custom "Developer API Name" field on a custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, custom-field, custom-object

I need to have a field that takes the text value of another field, and creates a developer API name out of it.

Ie.

`Object__c.Name = 'FAQ: How to use salesforce?'` gives `Object__c.APIName__c = 'FAQ_How_to_use_salesforce'`

I have a feeling only a trigger can properly do this, but I want to see if anyone has simpler alternatives? (ie, Formula field?)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, its just a formula field.

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Name, ":", "_"), " ", "_")
```